# MongoDB Child Only Search

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, nested

I'm currently trying to build a little program that requires user authentication.
I'm using MongoDB with it's official driver in C#.
Since every User has a parent Organization, I built the hierarchy like that:

- Organization

  - User

    - E-Mail
    - Password

Now, for my e-mail/password verification, I need to "loop through all organizations, check if the users email and password is correct and pick that user". I literally want to only receive the User back.

My approaches so far returned the organization with ALL users, which became quite messy.
I also want my method to be pretty perfomant, any ideas?

I've tried the Linq approach but that one turned out to not work due to type errors: (probably the most-understandable way though)

```
var q = from Organization in _orgs.AsQueryable()
from User in Organization.Users
select new User()
{
    EMailAddress = EmailPasswordCombo.Item1,
    Password = hashed
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to separate your collections, and add OrganizationId into User collection. After this you can easily pick all users or, one, that u need(by email for example). And sure it will be much faster than loop through all organizations and users.